# How to stop Windows Service if the process stuck for certain period of time?

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

How to stop Windows Service if the process stuck for certain period of time? As you see in the below code if the output of 'dblTimeElapsed' is more than 20 I need to restart the service.

```
dblTimeElapsed = (Now - dateTimeStart).ToString * 24 * 60 * 60

            FileIO.WriteLog("Time Elapsed : " & dblTimeElapsed)

            If dblTimeElapsed > 20 Then
                varResponse = vbCancel
                If varResponse = vbCancel Then
                    strStatus = "Log file busy.  Process aborted."
                    'Need to stop and restart the service here
                End If
                datTimeStart = Now
            End If
code continues....
```

Comment: What causes it to get stuck? [Cancel async tasks after a period of time (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict now and for all your code. You can find it in Project Properties for the current code. Then set it in Options for all your code.

Comment: When you turn on Option Strict you will see why `(Now - dateTimeStart).ToString * 24 * 60 * 60` won't work. I showed you how to do this in my answer to my to your last question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68073933/vb6-to-vb-net-conversion-syntax-print-to-streamwriter-reader

Comment: It is very silly to assign `vbCancel` to a variable and on the very next line check if the variable equals `vbCancel`.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a little bit of a design process issue here.  Self stopping and starting software is really not how services are supposed to work.  You really should be starting by looking at what is causing your service to be "stuck" and address that problem accordingly.  As I've said may times, at least during the development, create a console app which will allow you to debug your process easier.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, Mary, So I'm converting an old VB6 project to VB.NET and trying not to remove the codes in the original file and just trying to convert everything as it is since I don't want to end up lost situation. However I'm totally new to Visual Basic and trying to learn and convert at the same time. But I kind of figured too using 'vbCancel' is not ideal at this conversion from VB6 visual application to non visual Windows Service(however that's my job to do so). As Mary said I'll turn on Option Strict, I'll take whatever helps me at this point. Thanks!

Comment: @Hursey my job is to convert the VB6 application to a Windows Service but are you suggesting first convert it into a VB.NET console application and then convert it to a Windows Service? Because it's not possible to develop a Windows Service as a console app right? Please advice anything you know might help me, also I'm a new dev & like to develop my knowledge. Thank you & really appreciate it!

Comment: Create a windows console app that references your service project.  Effectively just a "pre-loader" so you can run the processes of your service without having to deploy it.  Means you don't have to fluff around with headaches of deploying your service, attaching debuggers etc.  That will allow you to at least get all the individual parts of your service running and debugged in a more accessible way